# How to loop through an array and print each item into an <li> tag using PHP?

Tags: php, html, arrays, for-loop

I'm trying to iterate through the array using php. I want the items to be stored in an `<li>` tag. I'm having trouble getting the names to print out. I can get a count of the array items printed, however not the names.

```
    <ul>
    <?php 
        $names = array('Mike', 'Chris', 'Jane', 'Bob');
        for($i=0; $i < count($names); $i++) {
            echo "<li>" . $i . "</li>";
        }
    ?>
</ul>
```

Comment: `$names[$i]`. you're spitting out the loop counter, not the array contents. http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php

Comment: I just reposted your code and altered it slightly with no explanation. I hope thats ok.

Comment: Thanks! I guess I could have explained it better but it seems pretty readable.

Comment: My bad. I received 10 simultaneous responses and just picked the first one I needed.

Comment: Oh man I totally misunderstood you lol. I thought you were going to repost this code in another post. Sorry bro!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<ul>
<?php 
    $names = array('Mike', 'Chris', 'Jane', 'Bob');
    foreach($names as $name) {
        echo "<li>" . $name . "</li>";
    }
?>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 2):

```
<ul>
    <?php 
        $names = array('Mike', 'Chris', 'Jane', 'Bob');
        foreach ($names as $name) {
            echo "<li>" . $name . "</li>";
        }
    ?>
</ul>
```

This is a little more natural than both imploding and looping through the array by index.

Your code wasn't working was because you were echoing the index of the name in the array rather than the actual name

Answer (score 1):

You need to echo the array not the count which is $i. So your echo should look like this:

```
echo "<li>" . $names[$i] . "</li>";
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work for you:

Just [`implode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php) your array, e.g.

```
echo "<li>" . implode("</li><li>", $names) . "</li>";
```

---

Your current code doesn't work, because your don't use your variable `$i` as index. So you would have to use:

```
$names[$i]
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to pull the index out of the array, otherwise you will just get 0,1,2,3...

```
<ul>
    <?php 
        $names = array('Mike', 'Chris', 'Jane', 'Bob');
        for($i=0; $i < count($names); $i++) {
            echo "<li>" . $names[$i] . "</li>";
        }
    ?>
</ul>
```

Answer (score -1):

Another way to code it would be:

```
<ul>
<?php $names = array('Mike', 'Chris', 'Jane', 'Bob'); ?>
<?php foreach ($names as $name) : ?>
<li><?php echo $name ?></li>
<?php endforeach ?>
</ul>
```